# How to access variables in an API view from my permission class in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

so I have this system set up so that whenever a POST, PUT or DELETE request is made to my API, I check for my shop's key in the header, and match it. I am trying to set this up using a permission class. I am doing the following:

**permissions.py**

```
SAFE_METHODS = ('GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS')

class BasePermission(object):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return True

class IsShopkeeperClient(BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        else:
            if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT' or request.method == 'DELETE':
                if not request.META.get('HTTP_SHOPKEY') == view.shop.key:
                    return False
                return True
```

Notice how I try to call `view.shop.key` in my permission. In my views, I am doing the following:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((IsShopkeeperClient,))
def categories_list(request, username):
    try:
        shop = Shop.objects.get(username=username)
        categories = shop.categories.all()
    except:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(categories, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = CategorySerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So, basically, the shop is a variable in my view. As a result of this, I get the following error:

> 'categories_list' object has no attribute 'shop'

Something along those lines. So, how can I pass on the shop to the permission class and access it from there? Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a class, it's easy to set the shop as a dynamic property.

```
class CategoriesList(APIView):

    permission_classes = (IsShopkeeperClient,)

    @property
    def shop(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_shop'):
            self._shop = Shop.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username'])
        return self._shop

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        # add the get code here

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        # add the post code here
```

Comment: I get the following error: `'Request' object has no attribute 'username'` when I try to get the shop in the view using `self.shop()`

Comment: Edited, should be self.kwargs['username'] if you named the group in the urls. If not, could be self.args[0]. Your mileage may vary depending on how you defined the associated url.

Comment: Thanks, now that's solved, however I can't seem to call it. It says shop is not callable. I have tried `self.shop()`, `self._shop()` from the view itself. Does not work.

Comment: That's a property, not a function so it'll be self.shop.categories.all()

Answer (score 0):

class IsShopkeeperClient(BasePermission):

```
def has_permission(self, request, view):
    if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
        return True
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST' or request.method == 'PUT' or request.method == 'DELETE':
            shop = Shop.objects.get(username=view.kwargs.get('username'))
            if not request.META.get('HTTP_SHOPKEY') == shop.key:
                return False
            return True
```